# Typescript Cannot find Module "fs" even though @types/node installed

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I know the usual fix for this one is to install @types/node , and I have 10.12.23 of that installed.

This appears to be a strange error and I am a bit baffled by it.  I have 2 other npm modules installed:  config ( which requires @types/config ) and firebase-admin which must have it's own typescript types.  Also using VS code version 1.31   . I even tried installing an older version of @types/node

The following works fine

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import fs from "fs";
```

The following fails: cannot find module 'fs'

```
import admin from "config";
import fs from "fs";
```

The following fails: cannot find module 'fs'

```
import fs from "fs";
```

I am not using any other packages / webpack or anything else. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Uh, you're saying `import fs from "fs";` works; then you're saying `import fs from "fs";` fails with "cannot find module "fs"?  Q: Which is it??? Q: What's "different" between failing/successful case?  FYI, "fs" is a "core NodeJS module" - it should *always* be available.

Comment: Yes , I know @paulsm4 ! crazy - I am baffled. it can only find fs if there is another module in the declaration that has built in types.  Maybe a bug in typescript or VS Code?

Comment: Could you try `import * as fs from "fs";` and see if that makes a difference for you? Also what is your `moduleResolution` in your TypeScript config set to?

Comment: Another suggestion: nuke the `node_modules` directory in your project folder, then run `npm install`.  And DEFINITELY stop and restart VSCode.

Comment: oh .. looks like some issue there.  Rebooted , run npm install and I get PERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\....\node_modules\@types\node\npm-shrinkwrap.json'

Comment: Ah thanks.  The node_modules directory showed empty in VS Code .. but it was not actually empty.  cleared everything out and working fine .  Thanks @paulsm4

Comment: Nuking `node_modules` worked for me too, thanks!

Comment: sadly the nuke didn't fix the issue for me :(

Answer (score 4):

Besides installing `@types/node`, check that the tsconfig.json:

- does not have a compilerOptions `types`, or make sure "node" is included there
- `noResolve` does not exist or is set to `false`
- `esModuleInterop` is set to `true` or you'll get error *Module "fs" has no default export*